# Networkx - Find individual hexagons in honeycomb structure

Tags: python, networkx

I am just working on this honeycomb-like structure network, which I generated by following the accepted answer from this thread: [Hexagonal lattice in different layers by networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222103/hexagonal-lattice-in-different-layers-by-networkx)

Copied below for convenience:

```
def node_dist(x,y, cx, cy):
    """Distance of each node from the center of the innermost layer"""
    return abs(cx-x) + abs(cy-y)


def remove_unwanted_nodes(G, m):
    """Remove all the nodes that don't belong to an m-layer hexagonal ring."""
    
    #Compute center of all the hexagonal rings as cx, cy
    cx, cy = m-0.5, 2*m -(m%2) #odd is 2m-1, even is 2m
    
    #in essence, we are converting from a rectangular grid to a hexagonal ring... based on distance.
    unwanted = []
    for n in G.nodes:    
        x,y = n
        #keep short distance nodes, add far away nodes to the list called unwanted
        if node_dist(x,y, cx, cy) > 2*m:
            unwanted.append(n)

    #now we are removing the nodes from the Graph
    for n in unwanted:
        G.remove_node(n)
        
    return G

m = 2 #change m here. 1 = 1 layer, single hexagon.
G = nx.hexagonal_lattice_graph(2*m-1,2*m-1, periodic=False, 
                               with_positions=True, 
                               create_using=None)
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')
G = remove_unwanted_nodes(G, m)

#render the result
plt.figure(figsize=(4,4)) 
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

This results in a plot like this:

[image]

How can one find all individual hexagons that form this honeycomb?

I tried cycles, cliques and chains but none of them seem to give me the answer I am after...unless I am doing something wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, the cycles you've specified don't have any nice graph theory properties.  Your best way is probably just going to be with knowledge of your graph.  Looking at the leftmost point in a hex say (a, b) the other points are (a, b+1), (a, b-1), (a+1, b), (a+1, b+1), and (a+1, b-1).

Answer (score 1):

I believe `nx.simple_cycles()` is what you want, but if you try to call it on an undirected graph then you get an error saying that this algorithm isn't implemented for this graph type.

The following approach is inelegant and probably wouldn't scale well if you needed it to, but it achieves  the desired result.  You can cast your undirected graph as directed which just replaces all undirected edges with two directed edges, one in each direction.  You can then call `nx.simple_cycles()` on it, limit to cycles of length 6, and de-dupe your 6-cycles based on the set of nodes present in each cycle:

```
DG = G.to_directed()
cycles = nx.simple_cycles(DG)
hex_cycles = [path for path in cycles if len(path) == 6]
hex_loops = []
for cycle in hex_cycles:
    if set(cycle) not in [set(loop) for loop in hex_loops]:
        hex_loops.append(cycle)
```

which gives `hex_loops` as desired:

```
[[(3, 4), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 6), (3, 5)],
 [(3, 4), (2, 4), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3)],
 [(0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (0, 4), (0, 3)],
 [(0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 6), (1, 5), (1, 4), (0, 4)],
 [(2, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1)],
 [(2, 4), (2, 5), (1, 5), (1, 4), (1, 3), (2, 3)],
 [(2, 7), (1, 7), (1, 6), (1, 5), (2, 5), (2, 6)]]
```