# How to create a hexagonal (ring) lattice with linear scaling?

Tags: networkx

With the command

```
networkx.hexagonal_lattice_graph(n,n)
```

I can create a lattice graph easily.

At [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222103/hexagonal-lattice-in-different-layers-by-networkx), there is an interesting solution to get a ring-like hexagon lattice starting from the networkx command. Unfortunately, the solution scale quadratically on the input.

I need to work with a linear scale-up on n.

Instead the networkx method scales as a 2nd degree function.

What I have in mind is to start from n *tiles* and iteratively add them in "vortex" fashon.

This would be linear on n.

Any solution?

Here some graphical example made by hand.

[image: This shows 6 tiles]

By adding another tile, we get exactely what is intuitively referred as haxagonal lattice ring:

[image]

Ultimately, the one below is the case with 17 tiles.

[image]

Comment: What is a vortex function? What is a hexagonal ring lattice? What are your desired inputs and outputs? If you sketch out what you want to happen and show that you've put some work and thought into this problem already, I think people will be less likely to downvote and be willing to help you. As it stands, you've used terms that aren't clearly defined and your objectives are unclear, so it's challenging to offer any advice.

Comment: I added some picture to make it more understandable. Thank you.